# Remove all text starting from a specific character

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file setup like

```
TEXT1:TEXT2
```

Basically lines of text separated by a `:`

I would like all text to the right of the `:` gone,
so `TEXT1:TEXT2` would turn into just `TEXT1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using cut

We tell `cut` that our field separator is a colon, `-d:`, and that we want to select the first field, `-f1`:

```
$ cut -d: -f1 file
TEXT1
```

#### Using sed

We tell sed to remove the first colon on a line and everything after:

```
$ sed 's/:.*//' file
TEXT1
```

#### Using grep

We tell grep to select the first part of each up to but not including the first colon:

```
$ grep -o '^[^:]*' file
TEXT1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '{$0=$1}1' infile
TEXT1
```

make ":" as your delimiter and then set column1 as your record.

Comment: This looks short and elegant. however it hides problem. say I have a line: `0:7`, what does your program give? If you want to stick in this way without `{...}`, you may try `($0=$1)||1` or `($0=$1)+1`

Comment: `awk -F: '$0=$1' infile`

Comment: I like this one, it's very elegant ++

Answer (score 1):

Below script

```
awk -v FS=":" '{print $1}' file
```

would also give you the same result.

Comment: Don't forget the curly braces around your action:  `awk ... '{print $1}' ...`

Comment: @jas : Good note :)

Answer (score 0):

In AWK, replace everything after the `:` with nothing:

```
$ awk 'sub(/:.*/,"",$0)' test
TEXT1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed -i.bkp 's/:.*//' infile.txt
```

This will also change the file inplace and create a backup file named `infile.txt.bkp`

Using `grep`

```
grep -oP '.*(?=:)' infile.txt
```